# Embedded microstrip antenna

Tags: rf, bluetooth, pcb-antenna, microstrip, potting

How well known are embedded microstrip antennas in general and are they feasible. I want to pot a 2.4 Ghz antenna for product reliability/water and shock proof reasons, but finding information and sources on this has been difficult.

What I have gauged so far is that this antenna will probably need to be custom designed, I have not found any freely available examples for reference so far. I presume as long as it's properly designed and tuned it will function as well as a normal designed against air antenna. In my specific application it would be a potted PCB antenna.

Input and any sources are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Plenty of people design and use microstrip antennas.  I'm not expert (or even beginner) in this, so I won't post an answer.  Search for "microstrip calculator" on this site and on google.  The warning I'll offer is that I suspect your plans to pot this may REALLY mess around with dielectric properties, and screw up all the equations.

Comment: I'm very well aware of the changes the dielectric imposes, that is exactly why i asked the question, it's specifically aimed towards potted antennas. That is  why a online microstrip calculator will not work at all, since it's a antenna embedded into a dielectric.

Comment: You might want to search for "antenna on ground" (leave the quotes in), but this isn't quite the same situation as the potting compound obviously won't be grounded.  I think you're well into consultant territory, (unless you're well equipped for RF testing and are ready to deal with quite a few iterations) with the contract such that a goodly chunk of payment comes with delivery of an antenna that meets spec.  I'd be concerned that a few mm difference in potting from unit to unit could detune, so you might want to think about consistent potting before sharing the job out.

Comment: Another avenue might be to go with a chip antenna instead of a microchip, and try to take advantage of the design engineers at the antenna makers for their recommendation.  You may still have issues with your transmission line to the chip.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your point on the potting variability is likely spot on. Wouldn't you agree though that chip antennas are not likely to perform well after potting, since they are made to radiate against air. As a side node i guess i have a possibility of doming a chip antenna as long as the dome encapsulates the near field. Once it has been radiated it should pass through a potting dielectric.

Comment: That's why I suggested searching for antenna on ground, which might help.  I've seen them used on wearable devices.

Answer (score 1):

These antenna design are IP(Intellectual property) of an oraganisation used in Semi-custom development,developing a patch antenna can be done easily,but doing it as an separate entity I guess can be done using a 3D printer.

You can build you Full Custom design, the main elements are the maintenance of the fringe-fields across the dielectric-ground plate and dielectric-patch boundary, you must apply boundary condition to check the radiation pattern and its range.

I would suggest you read Microstrip Antenna Design Handbook
 By Ramesh Garg.
Some document specifying the many other circuits production using 3D print are [given here](http://emlab.utep.edu/pdfs/Deffenbaugh_PhD_Dissertation.pdf).
See page 123 gives you all possible dimensions of the Patch now you have to design a radiating driver circuit.Best of Luck.